# To Map AggregateIterable<Document> to a class

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, bson

I am performing an aggregation pipeline over mongodb database. Generated result is in the form of AggregateIterable  which is needed to be mapped to java pojo class.

#MyClass.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Document(collection = "myCollection")
public class ODSMongo {
    
    @Field("_id")
    @Id
    private String _id;
    private String Key;
    private String projectKey;
    private Long highestIndex;
    private Long type;
    private Long exists;
}
```

#app.java

```
AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                match(new Document("projectKey", "myProject")),
                new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$Key")
                        .append("maxQuantity", new Document("$max", "$highestIndex"))
                        .append("docs", new Document("$push", new Document("_id", "$_id").append("Key", "$Key")
                                .append("highestIndex", "$highestIndex").append("exists", "$exists").append("type", "$type")))),
                new Document("$project",
                        new Document("_id", 0L).append("docs",
                                new Document("$filter", new Document("input", "$docs").append("as", "doc").append(
                                        "cond",
                                        new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$$doc.highestIndex", "$maxQuantity"))))))));


Iterator<Document> iterator = output.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next().get("docs"));
    }
```

After performing above operations, the output which get is

```
[Document{{_id=56, Key=AGS, highestIndex=1, exists=1, type=0}}]
[Document{{_id=41, Key=GFT, highestIndex=1, exists=1, type=0}}]
[Document{{_id=78, Key=ZAS, highestIndex=85, exists=1, type=0}}]
[Document{{_id=42, Key=O.ZAD, highestIndex=85, exists=1, type=0}}]
[Document{{_id=12, Key=MAH, highestIndex=936, exists=1, type=0}}]
[Document{{_id=21, Key=GOA, highestIndex=85, exists=1, type=0}}]
```

Please let me know how can I fetch each value of the key as well as map the entire result to the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch each value like a Map<Key, Value>:

```
    Document document = iterator.next();
    Integer id = document.containsKey("id") ? document.get("id", Integer.class) : null;
    String key = document.containsKey("key") ? document.get("key", String.class) : null;
    //   after collect each value, you can instantiate your object
    YourObject obj = new YourObject();
    obj.setId(id);
    obj.setKey(key);
    //...
```